# White lines crossing rendered cube

Tags: rendering, three.js

[image: lines on render cube issue illustrated]

I got this while trying to render a cube on Three.js, using THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() and a loaded texture.

Is this normal? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Set the option `overdraw:true`.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: true } );
```